# It is possible to create any metal?

Tags: metal, materials, elements

This question just popped up in head. There are many things which we are good at. We are good at:

- constructions.
- build stuff.
- destroying things.
- repairing things.
- cleaning.

But I want also to know, if it is possible to create for example: Beryllium, Gold, Iron, Silver and Platinum.

**Question:** Are we humans able to create natural metals? Or,it is impossible?

If it is possible for us to create any kind of metals, then, can you grant me informations of how or what substances I need to use for creating each metal? I have found in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHsPkoO4wKw) that shows you can create gold, but what about other metals? Are we capable of doing so? If we create metals, then do they have the same value and resistance just like the metals which are found in mountains and underground?

Just in curiosity.

**NOTE:** I’ve used on list “destroying” because, that’s how I see. Because, I have seen on a video about pollution, that we humans almost brought our home world to an end due to our ignorance. And that’s from where I got this idea. We’re incapable of taking care of our world.

Comment: Not sure if much Be was formed in the Big Bang (Physics SE has good questions/answers on nucleosynthesis in the Big Bang), but all the rest were formed later through nuclear reactions. Yes, they can all be made artificially at ridiculous cost.

Comment: Yes, can be done. After all this is how they make the super-heavy elements

Comment: Related: [Turn lead into gold via radioactive decay](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15541/16683), [Would it be possible to destroy gold?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/97731/16683), [Can we goldify metals?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/8455/16683), [Why can't we use fusion to make ourselves rich?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37486/16683), [Will adding up protons and electrons (without neutrons) create a new element?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37486/16683)

Comment: I'm not migrating this. It's on topic for Chemistry, possibly not for Physics. Just because Physics has questions on the Big Bang doesn't mean that this should be migrated, that's a bit of an overreaction - your question isn't even remotely about the Big Bang. Jon was just describing how the elements were made naturally, the point being that humans are capable of mimicking the nuclear reactions which formed the heavier metals.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of creating metals is from alchemy, which was the ancient forerunner to chemistry. This belief started to become debunked after Robert Boyle published "The Sceptical Chymists" in the 1600's.

In 1785,  Antoine Lavoisier, discovered the law of conservation of mass which states mass is not created or destroyed, it merely changes form. This law is one of the foundations of modern chemistry.  Even in the video, it states the gold is not being created it is merely changing form.  In the discipline of chemistry, it is considered not possible to create any metal.

Outside the discipline of chemistry in the discipline of physics it was discovered mass and energy are interchangeable.  This has given rise to the idea of nuclear transmutation.  Nuclear transmutation is certainly possible; however, it is an incredibly expensive feat which is often considered too impractical for consideration in the practice of practical chemistry.